# bootstrap3, django: pull-right didn't work

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am facing a problem building a django project:

the `pull-right` class in bootstrap 3 didn't work in django template [pull-right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZ7k3.png)

here is my code

```
{% block content %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4  pull-right">
        <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
        <form method="POST" action="">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form|crispy }}
            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Sign Up!">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: `doesn't work` is too vague...

Answer (score 1):

Put a div inside your column and apply the pull-right class on that one.

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="pull-right">
     <!-- content here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Why are you using columns if you want to pull it right?